# Prevent Windows from using keyboard layout when switching with Shift+Alt

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I currently have English and Russian keyboard layouts which I use frequently. Occasionally I also need Greek keyboard, which I'd like to install. But getting used to dealing with three layouts is a pain in the neck.

Also I'm not going to use Greek very often, so I don't want it to pop up when I switch layout with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. Is there a way to leave this layout and be able to use it by clicking on language bar on the taskbar and selecting it manually, but not through <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to remove a language from the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> list, but a workaround is to set shortcuts to the more common languages so that you can switch to them directly. Just type "language" in the start menu and open "Language settings" then select *Keyboard > Input language hot keys*

[image: Language settings]

[image: Input language hot keys]

There you can change the shortcut keys to English and Russian. You can even remove the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> combination from the list and only use the direct shortcuts exclusively

[image: Change key sequence]